# PHP require more server than ASP .NET?

Tags: php, asp.net, performance

Compiled code of ASP NET will perform much faster than PHP. Does that mean ASP NET need less server than PHP to perform equivalent application? Thus, ASP NET development able to save cost in hardware?

Comment: `less server`? when server becomes a unit?

Comment: Normally yes, that's why more and more developers are looking for ways how to improve the PHP compiler or even compile PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Any widely used programming language will be able to perform faster than PHP. Nobody is using PHP because it is fast.

And unless you are building something that requires tons of resources, speed is definitely not your primary issue, because even a small increase in development costs will dwarf what you'd  save hardware wise.

Comment: I found an article from facebook developer @ http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/ Speed was a major issue for facebook. With HipHop, they able to reduced the CPU usage by convert php to c++, an alternative for compiled code. then he mentioned "Less CPU means fewer servers"

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a good article](http://www.comentum.com/php-vs-asp.net-comparison.html) outlining your concerns. I have stripped out some of the points, but the following should answer your questions.

#### I. Scalability and Ease of Maintenance

Scalability and ease of maintenance have nothing to do with whether you select PHP or ASP.net platform. Web Application scalability and ease of maintenance primarily depend on:

- Programmers' experience
- Using the best programming practices
- Using a solid programming framework
- Following programming guidelines and standards

#### II. Performance and Speed

There has been much debate about this subject and most of the debates have been biased and have been tailored to promote one of the programming languages instead of informing the audience.

However, if the programming language needs to perform enormous tasks similar to the kind that sites such as Google or Yahoo do daily, then there should be a lot of consideration in selecting a very fast programming language for required enormous tasks — that is why Google and Yahoo use several programming languages (mostly open source), each selected to handle the tasks that the programming language is best at performing.

Below, I'm going to analyze the common and uncommon scenarios and explain which task is better than the other:

**1st Common Scenario:**
One of the common tasks of any web application would be to access and query the database and output the result to the web server and then to the browser. So on this common scenario, all the programming language is doing is communicating / interfacing with the database server and web server. On this common scenario, the speed of the programming language has almost no affect on this process; the speed of this process relies on the database server, web server, client's web browser / computer and bandwidth.

When it comes to the main and common database servers, MySQL (now owned by Oracle), PostgreSQL, MSSQL and Oracle are all fighting for speed and performance. We keep seeing new features and better performance by all database servers in each version upgrade so I will say that the above database servers will all have a great performance if the database programmers use optimized and practical SQL queries and if needed, use the advanced features such as caching.

MySQL is used by Google, Facebook, YouTube, Yahoo and recently on FIFA World Cup which received a huge audience around the World. So I would not question the capability of the MySQL database server.

Based on my research on a few online stats, as of this writing, the communication and interfacing between PHP and MySQL is faster than ASP.net and MSSQL but it is not very noticeable.

**2nd Common Scenario:**
One of the other common tasks of any web application would be to access the file system, find an image and send it to the web server. In this case, again, the programming language is doing very little — it is the Operating System and the file system that has the burden of communicating with the programming language.

Based on my research on a few online stats, as of this writing, the Linux OS and ext4 (file system) performs better (IO) than Windows OS and NTFS (file system.)

**3rd Common Scenario:**
Most Linux / Unix servers are run very lean without any extra un-needed packages or GUI interfaces and therefore the OS uses a lot less CPU and RAM which provides more allocation to the database and web server.

Most windows servers run clunky and with many un-needed packages and GUI which will be using much more CPU and RAM.

Obviously, a LAMP platform will have an advantage over the ASP.net platform because it will have more available resources.

**4th Not Very Common Scenario:**
ASP.net is usually written in C# (pronounced C Sharp) — generally speaking, as of this writing, C# is a faster programming language than PHP. (This may change as each programming language will come up with upgrades to fight for a better speed.) So if the programming language needs to run a 2,000,000 loop execution of a calculation, an ASP.net written in C# will win over PHP. However, this is a very uncommon scenario, the most loop executions of a calculation would be in 100s and not 2,000,000s. And in this case, there should be other concerns about why someone needs to do a 2,000,000 loop calculation.

Additional items that can have an effect on performance but have nothing to do with which programming language is selected are:

Ability and knowledge of programmer(s) to optimize the code
Ability and knowledge of programmer(s) to write proper and optimized SQL queries.
Functionality required (some functions may take longer to execute in the ASP.net platform and less time in PHP platform and vice versa.

#### III. Cost:

PHP, MySQL server, PostgreSQL server, Apache server, and Linux OS are all free and upgrades are also free. In addition, there is no additional licensing cost for having another hot standby server as a backup, or needing to run multiple servers for load balancing or server clustering.

LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP) is also much more popular among hosting companies, and its popularity results in a lower monthly hosting cost for LAMP hosting compared to Windows hosting.

ASP.net and IIS are free if you purchase Windows OS. There is a substantial licensing cost for a Microsoft Windows Server, Microsoft SQL Server and future upgrades. For example, Microsoft Server 2008 R2 Standard - 64-bit cost is about $1029 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition For Small Business cost approximately $1038.

**The above licensing costs for Microsoft can substantially increase if the site becomes popular and there is a need to run the site on multiple servers or requires server features such as load balancing, server clustering or hot standby.**

#### V. Time to Deploy

It takes a larger amount (more lines) of code to accomplish complex features and functionality with ASP.net compared to PHP, adding more time to the development process.

Additionally, PHP is interpreted at the server, so when changing a functionality, no additional steps are required to see the changes. On the other hand, ASP.net needs to be compiled each time the code is modified. Again, the development process is more time-consuming when using ASP.net as opposed to PHP.

#### VI. Platform Independent

PHP is platform independent and can run on any platform — Linux, Unix, Mac OS X, Windows.

ASP.net is built to run only on Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

Ageed with gintas, but it's not only about development costs. For typical web tasks language performance is not a bottleneck, it's usually database and webserver performance that are. So you should be better concerned about database, OS and http server to consume more "server". :)

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the answer is "it depends".

Many web applications are not constrained by the speed of execution on the web server layer - typically they run database queries or contact some other resource to magic things onto a page. This tends to have a far more noticable impact on performance than the difference between compiled and interpreted code.

Secondly, PHP and ASP.Net both use a lot of libraries, which are compiled; the total amount of code that executes for a given web request is far larger than the application code. This tends to reduce the impact of the difference between compiled versus interpreted code.

Thirdly, I have experience using both platforms; in practice, PHP and ASP.Net sites tend to have roughly comparable performance and scalability characteristics; if anything, PHP sites are slightly faster.